# Ruby On Rails: 404 Handle via standard way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

Would it be a good idea to add an standard internal 404 page (not in public but in app/view/shared/ folder). A page where user can move to other existing pages via menu / links etc.

Many good websites allow user to browse their site menu on 404. i.e. If in you login into facebook and click some [404 facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/9oi1=). YOu will see feeds chats with 404.

Well, In rails I don't know How to do this. well, I google-ed on it.

and What I found (Should be done to handle 404):

```
render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
```

What I currently have :

```
render :text => 'User not found', :status => 404`
```

**What I want to do : (if its not bad solution of handling 404):**

```
render :file => '/view/shared/404.html.erb', :status => 404
```

Please suggest!

Comment: Why don't you just write a controller with corresponding view files, etc.? As also mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19279062/2295964)?

Answer (score 1):

Try rendering like:

```
render "shared/404", :status => 404
```

I haven't tried it but from what's said in [Two controllers for one shared view in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472817/two-controllers-for-one-shared-view-in-ruby-on-rails) answer, this might work.